# Comparing two separate directories for directories and files within

Tags: shell-script, diff

To compare the structure by iterating through each and every folder, I have tried to list the output(to a text file) of every directory and file present :

```
diff --brief -Nr dir1/ dir2/ > out.txt
```

The output I have got is only for difference in files. I want the output which will iterate through the folders and specify if the folder exists in another directory.This should be valid for complete structure, files as well as folders.

`cat out.txt`:

```
Files abc/def/xy.txt and pqr/def/xy.txt differ
Files abc/ooo/q.txt and pqr/ooo/q.txt differ
Files abc/ooo/t.txt and pqr/ooo/t.txt differ
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two diretory trees: `dir_one` and `dir_two`. Then, assuming bash:

To list all that is in **both** `dir_one` and `dir_two`:

```
comm -12 <(cd dir_one ; find | sort) <(cd dir_two ; find | sort)
```

To list all that **is** present in `dir_one`, but **not** in `dir_two`:

```
comm -23 <(cd dir_one ; find | sort) <(cd dir_two ; find | sort)
```

And lastly, to list all that is **not** in `dir_one`, but **is** present in `dir_two`:

```
comm -13 <(cd dir_one ; find | sort) <(cd dir_two ; find | sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the output which will iterate through the folders and specify
>   if the folder exists in another directory

Consider these directories/files:

```
tree dir1/ dir2/
dir1/
|-- bar
|-- foo
`-- subdir_dir1
dir2/
`-- foo
```

Wouldn't this `diff` variant meet your needs?

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
Only in dir1: bar
Only in dir1: subdir_dir1
```